# Receive intent with null data between activities

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, bundle

I have an activity which send a data to another activity using intent as bellow :

```
public void periodDateSharedPreferences(int calculatedPeriodYear, int calculatedPeriodMonth, int calculatedPeriodDay)
{
  SharedPreferences periodDatePreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = periodDatePreferences.edit();
  editor.putInt("periodChosenDay",calculatedPeriodDay);
  editor.putInt("periodChosenMonth",calculatedPeriodMonth);
  editor.putInt("periodChosenYear",calculatedPeriodYear);
  editor.commit();
    Toast.makeText(birthDate.this,"The date was saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Intent saved2 = new Intent(birthDate.this,MenuActivity.class);
      saved2.putExtra("DueDateChanged", true);
startActivity(saved2);
    finish();
 }
```

and the other activity receive this intent as bellow :

```
static String DueDateChanged = "com.app.antiwal7amel.DueDateChanged";
```

---

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(MenuActivity.DueDateChanged);
        tv.setText(message);
        super.onResume();
```

but when I run it, I receive a null data in the intent ! where is the problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should retrieve the data using the same key that you used to put it:

```
String message = intent.getStringExtra("DueDateChanged");
```

as you used

```
saved2.putExtra("DueDateChanged", true);
```

**Note:**
    you are putting a boolean not a string, to add a string

```
saved2.putExtra("DueDateChanged", "yourString");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MenuActivity.class);
    intent.putExtras("yourBoolName", true);
```

Retrieve intent extra:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Boolean yourBool = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("yourBoolName");
}
```